# How to figure out where the script that is loading someting on a page via AJAX is located?

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging, firebug

I have a page that has some content loaded via ajax on dom ready. The page also has a ton of js files so I can't quickly skim them to see where the javascript responsible for loading the content is coming from. How can I do this using firebug?

Answer (score 0):

If the page is using a framework for ajax support like jQuery, you can set a breakpoint in the framework's ajax call and see what pieces of code are calling it when the breakpoints are hit.

If it's not using a framework, then it probably at least has a helper function for doing the ajax calls and you can set a breakpoint there.

If there are not even any helper functions, then you're going to have to grab all the sources and grep through them for where the ajax calls are being made.